# Enabling REQBILLINGADDRESS=1 on our SetExpressCheckout API between Sagepay and paypal

Tags: paypal, opayo

The company i work for want to return the billing address from paypal to sagepay because a customer recently emailed about an order she placed that was going to get delivered to her sister however the billing address for this order was the delivery address and not the address and name of the person who ordered and payed for the gifts.

Paypal have enabled the Billing Address Request toggle on both our Live and Sandbox accounts and have said Sagepay need to make the changes on SetExpressCheckout API call so allow the variable "REQBILLINGADDRESS=1" to be passed.

Would anyone have any idea how we do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, I'm afraid - Sage Pay handle the integration between themselves and PayPal - you can't pass extra parameters to change the behaviour.

Sage Pay would need to amend their integration with PayPal.